# How could agent Daniels survive in 31st century?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise

The ["Shockwave. Part II" episode](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Shockwave,_Part_II_(episode)) depicts

> 31st century's Earth as a place of total destruction. There are only debris of all buildings, there is no electricity, no water and... there is absolutely no human, except for Captain Archer and Daniels himself.

Is it explained somewhere in this episode

> how and why could Daniels be the only person surviving a total destruction that wiped out all other billions of humans?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable. The whole story is layered in "this is too complicated for your puny 22nd century human minds to handle" and, beyond that, we were never told the answer. Perhaps Daniels' proximity to a time machine, or his involvement in procuring Archer, were to blame. Or perhaps some other facet of his existence was responsible. Or the Universe "wanted" him to make it into this timeline so that he could help Archer get back. We just don't know, and you know we don't know.

Comment: This comment is a nearly perfect answer, I was expecting for this and all / most of all other of my questions -- whether some issue is or isn't explained in an episode or whether is a part of pure speculation. I'd say that you could change this comment into an answer, because nothing else I'd expect beyound that.

Comment: The script does not say they were the only humans. Besides, archer already asked him that in the scene. Daniels in-universe answer was, “it doesn’t work that way.”

Comment: "My advice in making sense of temporal paradoxes is simple: Don't even try." - Captain Janeway